# Как проверить есть ли в конкретном индексе строки символ? JAVA

Tags: java, строки, for, перебор

```
public class Output {
public static void output(int N, String I){
    for(int i = 0; i == I.length(); i++){
        if(I[i].equals("")){

        }
    }
}}
```

нужно проверить является ли символ I пробелом

Comment: вместо `""`  написать `" "` ?

Comment: это понятно, но вопрос в другом

Comment: "нужно проверить является ли символ I пробелом"  .........

Comment: да, это и нужно

Comment: I - это строка..... она не может быть символом))

Comment: ой, я имел ввиду "является ли символ i пробелом в строке I"

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1469759/#comment2630423_1469759

Comment: А зачем в данной функции параметр `N`?

Answer (score 2):

```
if (Character.isWhitespace(I.charAt(i))) 
    System.out.println("yes"); 
else
    System.out.println("no");
```

Вместо `isWhitespace` можно использовать `isSpaceChar` если нужно знать что это именно пробел, а не табуляция или перевод строки

Comment: а вдруг, ну а вдруг нужно именно пробел, а не табуляция или перевод строки?!

Comment: ок, добавил коммент

Comment: спасибо большое! Работает!

Comment: Если помогло - галочку тык!)

Answer (score 0):

У вас цикл не выполнится ни разу, так как он должен работать, пока `i` равно длине строки, начиная от 0:  для непустой строки это условие не выполнится никогда, а для **пустой** строки попытка прочитать символ по индексу 0 при помощи метода `String::charAt` приведёт к `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` или при чтении из пустого массива символов `I.toCharArray()[i]` будет выброшено `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```java
public static void output(int N, String I) {
    for (int i = 0, n = I.length(); i < n; i++) {
        if (' ' == I.charAt(i)) {
            // найден пробел по индексу i
        }
    }
}
```

или так:

```java
public static void output(int N, String I) {
    int i = -1;
    for (сhar c : I.toCharArray()) {
        i++;
        if (' ' == c) {
            // найден пробел по индексу i
        }
    }
}
```